# Difference between usage of an aggregate operator by chaining with Select and not doing that

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements, aggregate-functions

I wonder if there is a difference between the following statements in respect to both performance and calling-style(e.g. applied the expression to all sequences or objects).

```
var minPrice = SampleData.Books
                               .Min(book => book.Price);
var maxPrice = SampleData.Books
                               .Select(book => book.Price)
                               .Max();
```

or

```
var nbCheapBooks1 = SampleData.Books
                                    .Select(book => book.Price)
                                    .Where(book => book < 30).Count();

var nbCheapBooks2 = SampleData.Books
                                    .Select(book => book.Price)
                                    .Count(book => book < 30);

var nbCheapBooks3 = SampleData.Books
                                    .Count(book => book.Price < 30);
```

Comment: What is the runtime type of `SampleData.Books`?  That might be significant.  [LINQ performance Count vs Where and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25787555/150605) compares `.Count()` with `.Where().Count()` for a `List<>`.  And can you elaborate on the "calling-style" part of your question?  It seems like any differences there should be apparent.  Also, for clarity, after you do `.Select(book => book.Price)` I think subsequent lambda variables should be named `price`, not `book`.  Also related: [Difference between Where().Count() and Count()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23863853/150605)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just created a simple benchmark, based on your sample, and added one more method with filtering using `Where(book => book.Price < 30)` and count (which should be the fastest one)

```cs
[SimpleJob]
public class LinqBenchmark
{
    private IEnumerable<Book> Books;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Books = new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book { Price = 20 },
            new Book { Price = 30 },
            new Book { Price = 40 },
            new Book { Price = 50 },
            new Book { Price = 60 },
            new Book { Price = 70 },
            new Book { Price = 80 },
            new Book { Price = 10 }
        };
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int SelectWhereCount()
    {
        return Books.Select(book => book.Price).Where(book => book < 30).Count();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int SelectCount()
    {
        return Books.Select(book => book.Price).Count(book => book < 30);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int WhereCount()
    {
        return Books.Where(book => book.Price < 30).Count();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int Count()
    {
        return Books.Count(book => book.Price < 30);
    }

    internal class Book
    {
        public int Price { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

`Count` method with predicate works faster then other ones

[image]

You can refer to [implementation details](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b) to see and understand a performance difference. `Count(book => book.Price < 30)` pass each element in a loop to `Func<TSource, bool> predicate` and increments count, if gets `true`.

`Where` and `Select` under the hood use special [`WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,0e5ab1a57b7e1438) or [`WhereListIterator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,979cb1fc22e29394) class and then calculate the count. The reason why `Where` and `Count` works faster is perfectly explained in [LINQ performance Count vs Where and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787555/linq-performance-count-vs-where-and-count) thread, leave it here for the reference.

So, in terms of performance `Books.Where(book => book.Price < 30).Count()` is fastest option, in terms of readability two last options look more convenient, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

They are functionaly equivalent. I would prefer the shorter variants, i.e. `.Count(book => book.Price < 30)` simply because it is shorter. There might be some slight difference in performance. But if performance is the most important concern, a regular for-loop is usually faster, but less convenient and readable.

If you want to know the actual performance difference, test it. Insert a stopwatch and measure the execution time.

Comment: _but you would typically not use Linq in performance critical code_ doesn't sound coherently.

Comment: @snr, changed the wording.